# Force <a> and <img> to have the same height

Tags: html, css

I have a simple situation where I have an a-element containing an img-element. My problem is my a-element is a few pixels higher than my img-element. I always have a thin visible line of the a-element below the img-element.

[image]

The thin red line below the image is the background color of my a-element.

How can I remove this line?

Comment: why don't use `background-image` instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the vertical alignment on the image to top:

```
img {
    vertical-align:top;
}
```

You can see it work in the example below (comment out the vertical-align to see the gap re-appear).

```css
a {
  background: #faa;
}
img {
  vertical-align:top;
}
```

```html
<a href="#"><img src="http://www.placehold.it/200x200" /></a>
```

Comment: Alright, I thought it would be that simple in a way... But why do I need to do this? Why is there this line by default?

Comment: Will this change the position of the `img`, compared to anything else?

Comment: Because the gap for inline elements is reserved for descender font elements.

Answer (score 2):

Give `display: block` for `img` and `inline-block` for the `<a>`:

```
img {display: block;}
```

**Snippet**

```css
a {
  background: #ccf;
  display: inline-block;
}

img {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<a href="#"><img src="http://www.placehold.it/200x200" /></a>
```

Comment: @Rudie Added `inline-block` for `<a>`. Forgot to document it. Please check again.

Comment: In my case I would like to keep the display configuration my element already has, so I think I will use the way with vertical-align here, but for future cases that's also good to know. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try giving both a fixed height and width. For ex .

```
a {
width:50px;
height:50px;
}
img {
width:50px;
height:50px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
img{
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}
```

Don't explicitly define height and width of the image

Answer (score 0):

What I usually do is

```
a {
  display: inline-block;
}
img {
  display: block;
}
```

because I know how it works.

[Proof in a fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/rudiedirkx/2pcvbtjf/)

Answer (score -1):

You can use this line of code:

```
a, img {
height: (your height);
}
```

Hope this helped you!